# Combining number ranges out of several values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, numbers, logic

I have a logical challenge and I am wondering what would be best practice or possible methods or libraries to best solve the problem.

Let's say there are multiple arrays like `[10, 20, 30] ["24-30", "45-60"] [34, 35] ["28-33", 90]`

What I want is a overview of single ranges and distinct values without any redundancy. So out of upper arrays there should be generated a single sorted array with all values, which are merged to a logical ordered stream.

for example for the upper values I expect a string

```
[10, 20, "24-35", "45-60", 90]
```

so the logic should detect, that e.g. 30 is already included in `[24-30]`, that "28-33" continues and overlaps with "24-30" and "28-33" is continued by single values 34 and 35.

Maybe someone knows a library which supports me with that kind of problem or knows a good solution?

Comment: asking for library is offtopic. do you have something tried?

Comment: not yet. before i try something i am searching for possible solutions and learn about experience from others. i would be pretty capable to create some brutal solution, but maybe someone can offer a bit more elegant way like that way in my mind

Answer (score 3):

You could use a chained approach with changing the data structure, sorting an reassembling the connected parts.

```js
var data = [[10, 20, 30], ["24-30", "45-60"], [34, 35], ["28-33", 90]],
    result = data
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            a.map(function (b) {
                var c = b.toString().split('-')
                c[1] = c[1] || c[0];
                r.push(c.map(Number));
            });
            return r;
        }, [])
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]; })
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1] || [];
            if (a[0] <= last[1] + 1) {
                if (last[1] < a[1]) {
                    last[1] = a[1];
                }
                return r;
            }
            return r.concat([a]);
        }, [])
        .map(function (a) {
            return a[0] === a[1] ? a[0] : a.join('-');
        });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: that was coming that fast to your mind? Im feeling just stupid right now. Thank you Nina. Thats exactly what i need.

Comment: no worries. i am actual writing an approach without sorting first and the last reduce part was my starting point.